# RDLC Export to Word Showing a blank extra page

Tags: ms-word, rdlc

Im using RDLC for VS 2010 and exporting the graph to a word document gives one extra blank page (its not showing in PDF though). All of the dimensions in Report, Chart and Body are set 11x8.5 with no margins. I just wonder what could be causing the blank page in Word.

Comment: I have the very same issue

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same problem and managed to solve it by adjusting the layout of my report.

Basically I moved all of my rectangles/tables etc to sit tightly next to each other, eliminating any white space where possible and also resized the report to be as small as possible, i.e. sit tightly against its contents.

It might also be worth enabling the report option to 'ConsumeContainerWhitespace'.

I suspect Word uses its own pagination logic, which is why you see a difference between pdf and doc.  So it may just be the case that your report is over-running very slightly into the next page and saving a little space on the report may prevent this.

I realise this is not a precise answer, but I hope it helps nonetheless.